# Else no posts found in foreach loop with while

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, while-loop

This is on a CPT archive with Taxonomy terms , i can't get the 'No posts found' to show up ? the loop works , it displays each term name as a heading and shows the posts under each term in a list. I have tried a lot of code to get the 'No posts found' to show up ... nothing is working ?

```
<?php


//fetch the terms for the policy taxonomy
  $terms = get_terms( 'policy-groups', array(
  'hide_empty' => 'true',
) );

// run a query for each policy-group term
foreach( $terms as $term ) :
   $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'policies',
    'policy-groups' => $term->slug ,
    'order'        => 'DSC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );  
     if( $query->have_posts() ) :  ?>

       <ul>

         <?php
         // output the policy-group name in a heading tag               
         echo'<h4 class="policy-archive-heading">' . $term->name . '</h4>'; 

         // Start while the Loop   
          while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
             $attachment_id = get_field( "policy_upload" );
             $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
          ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(  ); ?></a>
            </li>  


<?php endwhile; //endwhile ?>

<?php else: printf( __('<strong>Sorry , No posts were found</strong>')); ?>

<?php endif; //end if posts ?>

</ul>

<?php endforeach ?>


// use reset postdata to restore orginal query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I don't think this can work , because 'IF' there are no posts it will never get to the 'Else' ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not displaying the `terms` which have no `posts`. For showing the terms having no posts, change the `'hide_empty' => 'false'` in your code.

Please find your updated code of $terms query:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'policy-groups', array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

And also correct your $args query, please find the code below:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'policies',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax-query'   => array(
              array( 
                 'taxonomy' => 'policy-groups',
                 'field' => 'slug',
                 'term' => $term->slug,
              )
         ),
        'orderby'     =>  'title',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
```

And also place the opening `'<ul>'` tag before the `if( $query->have_posts() )` condition or place the closing `'</ul>'` just after '`endwhile;`', as they are not properly synchronized.

After all the correction, here is your full code, copy & replace with your code:

```
<?php
//fetch the terms for the policy taxonomy
  $terms = get_terms( 'policy-groups', array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
) );

// run a query for each policy-group term
foreach( $terms as $term ) :
   $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'policies',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax-query'   => array(
              array( 
                 'taxonomy' => 'policy-groups',
                 'field' => 'slug',
                 'term' => $term->slug,
              )
         ),
        'orderby'     =>  'title',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );  ?>
    <ul>
        <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) :  
            // output the policy-group name in a heading tag               
            echo'<h4 class="policy-archive-heading">' . $term->name . '</h4>'; 

            // Start while the Loop   
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                $attachment_id = get_field( "policy_upload" );
                $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(  ); ?></a>
                </li>  


            <?php endwhile; //endwhile ?>

        <?php else: printf( __('<strong>Sorry , No posts were found</strong>')); ?>

        <?php endif; //end if posts ?>

    </ul>

<?php endforeach ;
// use reset postdata to restore orginal query
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Please change the `'order' => 'ASC/DESC'` as per your requirement in the above queries.

I hope, it may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for trying , but that doesn't work. If i use your edited code , the actual term headings display correctly , but the posts in the list under them are showing all posts , regardless of the term they are assigned. under each term heading should only be the terms assigned to that policy-group. My original code works for achieving this , but does not show the 'no posts found'. Additionally , your code also does not show the 'no posts found'.

Comment: Sorry brother, my mistake, please remove single inverted comma(' ') from 'false', just write it as 'hide_empty' => false. Please try it once. I have already updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for trying , but same result for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would change a couple of things:

- Search by term id
- Only publish posts
- Move reset postdata to right location
- Typo in DESC order

Code below:

```
 <?php


    //fetch the terms for the policy taxonomy
      $terms = get_terms( 'policy-groups', array(
      'hide_empty' => 'true',
    ) );

    // run a query for each policy-group term
    foreach( $terms as $term ) :
       $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'policies',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax-query'   => array(
              array( 
                 'taxonomy' => 'policy-groups',
                 'term' => $term->term_id
              )

        ),
        'order'        => 'DSC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

      $query = new WP_Query( $args );  
         if( $query->have_posts() ) :  ?>

           <ul>

             <?php
             // output the policy-group name in a heading tag               
             echo'<h4 class="policy-archive-heading">' . $term->name . '</h4>'; 

             // Start while the Loop   
              while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                 $attachment_id = get_field( "policy_upload" );
                 $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
              ?>

                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(  ); ?></a>
                </li>  


    <?php endwhile; //endwhile ?>

    <?php else: printf( __('<strong>Sorry , No posts were found</strong>')); ?>

    <?php endif; //end if posts ?>

    </ul>

    <?php 
      // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
      wp_reset_postdata();
         endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying , but that doesn't work either , same result as in my comment to Prateek Verma